# python change json data from a key string

Tags: python, json

I have a json data which has another json data as its values. I want to change the value of a key. Key is given with separator dot(.)

```
import json    
data1='{"name":"xxx","info":{"mark":{"sub1":"11","sub2":22,"sub3":{"sub31":22,"sub32":44}}},"avg":33.33}'
data=json.loads(data1)
key="info.mark.sub3.sub32"
value=98
```

How can i change the value of the key without doing like this `data["info"]["mark"]["sub3"]["sub32"]=value` ?

Comment: Split on the dot (`key.split('.')`) and use the `reduce()` approach I linked you to.

Comment: I'm not sure reduce can be used to set the value, so I just put this here

    keys = key.split('.')
    res = data
    for i, k in enumerate(keys):
         if k in res:
             if i == len(keys) - 1:
                 res[k] = value
             else:    
                 res = res[k]

Comment: @MartijnPieters i got the values using reduce() function. But i couldnt set the values.

Comment: @DinoopNair: you can get the *parent* key and set the value on the returned dictionary with the last element.

Comment: still i couldn't find the solution.